# Prevent Overwrite Warning in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a macro to extract XML data from a Web API into a spreadsheet. The first column contains two fields delimited with a comma so I have extended the macro to insert a column then run Text to Columns to split out the data.

The macro works really well, but I get an annoying warning asking if I want to replace the data:

[image]

Is there a way to suppress the warning?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

source: [SolutionSite](http://www.excely.com/excel-vba/disable-alert-warning-messages.shtml)

To suppress the warnings:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

To activate the warnings:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

Two important points from the [documentation:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839782%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

> [...] when a message requires a response, Microsoft Excel chooses the default response.

and

> If you set [DisplayAlerts] to False, Microsoft Excel sets [it back] to True when the code is finished [...]

meaning you'll still have the standard "Do you want to save before closing?" etc. prompts during normal Excel use.

Comment: Awesome! Works a treat.

Answer (score 1):

I found a scenario where neither `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` nor `Application.AlertBeforeOverwriting = False` work.

When running some of the Data Analysis Add-In tools the messaging is bypassed. Whilst not ideal, I found a solution from [prsthlm](https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/index.php?thread/84268-suppress-overwrite-existing-data-alert-in-vba-macro/) whereby one uses `Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}"` before the `Run` method call to handle the overwrite pop-up. E.g.

Pseudo code:

```
With Application
    .SendKeys "{ENTER}"
    .Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Histogram", range1  _
    , range2, range3, False, _
    True, True, False
End With
```