# Macro enabled word documents give save changes dialogue

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've a VBA script as below.

```
Sub AutoOpen()
  ActiveDocument.Variables("LastOpen").Value = Now()
End Sub

Sub AutoClose()
  Dim objFSO, objFolder, objTextFile, objFile
  Dim strDirectory, strFile, strText
  strDirectory = "d:\work"
  strFile = "\work.csv"

  ' Create the File System Object
  Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

  ' Check that the strDirectory folder exists
  If objFSO.FolderExists(strDirectory) Then
     Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strDirectory)
  Else
     Set objFolder = objFSO.CreateFolder(strDirectory)
     Debug.Print "Just created " & strDirectory
  End If

  If objFSO.FileExists(strDirectory & strFile) Then
     Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strDirectory)
  Else
     Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strDirectory & strFile)
     Debug.Print "Just created " & strDirectory & strFile
  End If

  Set objFile = Nothing
  Set objFolder = Nothing
  ' OpenTextFile Method needs a Const value
  ' ForAppending = 8 ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2
  Const ForAppending = 8

  Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strDirectory & strFile, ForAppending, True)

  'Build the string to write
  strText = """" & ActiveDocument.FullName & """" & "," & ActiveDocument.Variables("LastOpen").Value & "," & Now()

  ' Writes strText every time you run this VBScript
  objTextFile.WriteLine (strText)
  objTextFile.Close
End Sub
```

here the macro is running fine, but the problem is when i open and close my word document, though there are no changes done, it asks me if i would like to save the changes like below.

[image]

please let me know how can i avoid this save dialogue box, if there are no changes made in document.

here if i open a blank document and close it, even then this is getting triggered.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent Overwrite Warning in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25739577/prevent-overwrite-warning-in-vba)

Comment: Your `AutoOpen` has made changes to the doc, just not in displayable context.

Comment: Hi @PatricK, how can i fix this?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett I've added the change as given there in that link, but there is no effect and in the left panel i.e. the properties list i don't see this option even. I use office 2007.

Comment: Right... This is Word VBA. That wasn't clear to me initially. I added the [tag:word-vba] tag to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, the creation of the variable in AutoOpen is causing this behavior.

Include a `Save` statement in AutoOpen:

```
Sub AutoOpen()
  ActiveDocument.Variables("LastOpen").Value = Now()
  ThisDocument.Save
End Sub
```

to avoid the Save prompt.